# Negate the statement and re-express as an equivalent positive statement.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Need help with this homework problem. I need to negate the statement and then re-express it as a positive statement. I've searched online and haven't been able to find an answer. I'm having trouble grasping quantificational logic so thanks in advance to whoever helps.

Original statement:

> Everyone is happy sometimes, but no one is happy all the time.

My attempt at symbolizing the statement: let x = be happy sometimes and y = to be happy all the time. ∀(x) ∧ ∃(¬y)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need two negations, one for each, otr one single negation of the whole "original statement"?

Comment: You must have attempted to symbolize the original statement before negating it ... can you post your attempt?

Comment: You really need a 2-var statement like $h(x,t)$ for $x$ is happy at time $t$ to symbolize these. Everyone happy sometime then is for all x exists t so h(x,t). no one happy all the time is then (not)[exists x) (for all t) h(x,t)], These can be put together using "and" for the "but" in original statement. [So far this has not been negated]

Comment: You cannot nagate variables: $x,y,\ldots$. In quantificational logic (aka *predicate logic*) we have variables (to be quantified) and predicates. With them we form sentences and we have to use *logical connective* : $\lnot, \land, \ldots$ with sentences.